# Change Active Directory DNS replication from Domain level to Forest

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

Currently I have an active directory running on windows server 2008 with integrated DNS.
The DNS Zone files are set to be replicated Domain wide for one of our domains.
I want to change it to being Forest wide replicated.

Is there a best practice way to make this change?

EDIT:

This is an inherited network.
Environment, Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2.

3 AD servers in 2 sites

2 domains, one is the root of the forest eg contoso.com the other is just an AD domain within the forest, I will refer to the second as notcontoso.com

I am using AD DS-integrated replication of zone data for both domains.

However notcontoso.com is only replicated in the DomainDNSZone partition I would like to convert it or migrate it to being replicated in the ForestDNSZone partition.

Definitions of the replication scopes - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772101.aspx

Again, does anyone know of a best practice to change the replication from Domain to Forest.

Comment: Proper terminology is important, as is explaining a little more  about your environment and what you're trying to do, because as it stands your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Is there a best practice for what AD application partition you store your AD integrated DNS zones? I believe the best practice is to replicate the AD integrated zones to all DNS servers in the Forest.

Comment: I have edited the question to include extra information and hopefully clarify what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you mean by a "best practice" to change the DNS replication scope.  [You... just select your zone(s) and change the replication scope to the desired scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784148%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

In DNS manager, you'd right click your zone, and select `properties` from the context menu, then hit the `Change...` button next to `Replication`, and select the desired option from the radio button list.  (Screenshot below).

[image]

And, as with most things worth doing in Windows-world, you can even do it with PowerShell, these days, [and the documentation for how is found on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649865.aspx).

> Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone [-Name]  -ReplicationScope  [...]

Comment: My concern is that changing it may break it. I was hoping it was as simple as your answer but worried that there was something I was missing.

Comment: @Sam Ah, well - no worries.  It's as simple as as you hoped.